# Get single corresponding row based on lowest distance for each job

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, group-by

I'm building a system where a user can search using a zip code (soon multiple zip codes at once), and each "job" can have *up to three separate locations*. I need to return the ID of the **lowest distance** job, as well as the calculated distance and all other fields for the job.

I can calculate the distance for the jobs. I can even return one result per job.

But I can't return the *lowest distance* result per job.

I have put together an SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03b2c/10

**Sample data:**

Input: `SET @user_lat = 44.053575, @user_lng = -123.086493, @range = 50;`

```
ID  JOB_ID  LATITUDE    LONGITUDE               DISTANCE

9   1       44.063716888428 -123.08470916748    0
8   1       44.052070617676 -123.086753845215   0.81
7   1       44.035049438477 -123.047355651855   2.71

10  2       44.059913635254 -123.017936706543   3.32
11  2       44.045707702637 -122.930877685547   7.73
13  3       45.480751037598 -122.642738342285   100.21
```

**GROUP Results:** - each row is OK, but not the nearest distance.

```
ID  JOB_ID  LATITUDE        LONGITUDE           DISTANCE
7   1       44.035049438477 -123.047355651855   2.71
10  2       44.059913635254 -123.017936706543   7.73

ROUND( [math], 2 ) AS distance -- (full query below)
...
GROUP BY job_id

HAVING distance < @range

ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

**GROUP and Min() Results:** - the lowest distance is returned correctly, but not the correct ID.

```
ID  JOB_ID  LATITUDE        LONGITUDE           DISTANCE
7   1       44.035049438477 -123.047355651855   0
10  2       44.059913635254 -123.017936706543   3.32

MIN( ROUND( [math], 2 ) ) AS distance
...
GROUP BY job_id

HAVING distance < @range

ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

__

**What I need:** - The lowest distance is returned, and the ID matches that distance.

```
ID  JOB_ID  LATITUDE        LONGITUDE           DISTANCE
9   1       44.035049438477 -123.047355651855   0
11  2       44.059913635254 -123.017936706543   3.32
```

__

**FULL QUERY FROM GROUP RESULTS EXAMPLE**

```
set
  @user_lat = 44.063717, 
  @user_lng = -123.084706,
  @range = 2000;


-- Filter by distance, displaying the nearest location of each job in miles
select 
  *,

  -- We can use min() here to get the lowest distance, but this does not affect the ID returned!
  -- min( ... ) as distance

  ROUND(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN( (@user_lat - abs(loc.latitude))  * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@user_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(loc.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@user_lng - loc.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )), 2)
    as distance

from `locations` loc

group by job_id

having distance < @range

order by distance asc;
```

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried in the body of your question.

Comment: I added the code, a summary to each corresponding example and a full code example below. This is also all in the example fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c0f4/2). (The question is now quite a mess, heh).

Comment: You *definitely* need to include an aggregation function (such as `MIN`) in your query if you have a `GROUP BY`.  (Whether you want a `GROUP BY` is a separate issue; I haven't read enough to know.)

Comment: Some food for thought: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's mysql, you can make use of its special grouping implementation, making for a very simple query:

```
select * from (
  select *,
  ROUND(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN( (@user_lat - abs(loc.latitude))  * pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(@user_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS( abs(loc.latitude) * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((@user_lng - loc.longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )), 2) as distance
  from locations
  order by distance) loc
group by job_id
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. Here is the working fiddle with range qualifier: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03b2c/47

Comment: This actually makes perfect sense, you return all the results sorted normally and _then_ you group the results. This is what I was looking for, I just expected it to be some special "group" operator or something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've ignored the range bit for now...

If distance() was a function (it's easy to construct such a thing) then the query might look like this...

```
SELECT x.*
     , distance(x.latitude,x.longitude,@user_lat,@user_lng)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT job_id
            , MIN(distance(latitude,longitude,@user_lat,@user_lng)) min_distance 
         FROM locations 
        GROUP 
           BY job_id
     ) y
    ON job_id = x.job_id
   AND y.min_distance = distance(x.latitude,x.longitude,@user_lat,@user_lng);
```

Comment: I get it, you are equating the distance for each field and returning the minimum values, then comparing the minimum value itself to the distance of the field again. I think I'll stick with Bohemian's solution as I'm guessing it would be faster since it doesn't have to  perform the math twice, but thanks for the idea!